# DelegatingFilterProxy retrieving property values

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am having a `web.xml` with the below filter configuration.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>smplAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Bean definition for `smplAuthenticationFilter` is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="smplAuthenticationFilter" class="com.mycompany.ct.common.security.smpl.servletfilters.SmplActiveDirectoryServletFilter">
        <property name="databaseLoggerTarget" value="java:jdbc/smplDataSource" />
        <property name="smplSecurityCredentials" value="${adapter.security.smpl.credentials}" />
        <property name="smplSecurityPrincipal" value="${adapter.security.smpl.principal}" />
        <property name="smplSearchBase" value="${adapter.security.smpl.searchbase}" />
        <property name="smplProviderUrl" value="${adapter.security.smpl.providerurl}" />
        <property name="applicationName" value="smpl" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

In this, I would like to know from where the property values for `smplSecurityCredentials`, `smplSecurityPrincipal`, `smplSearchBase`, `smplProviderUrl` are set?

In otherwords, how to find the value for variables like  `${adapter.security.smpl.credentials}`?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file should also have some line such as:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="..."/>
```

The location (or locations in case of multiple files) will tell you where your properties are

This placeholder declaration may not necessarily reside in the same configuration file.
It must be placed in the same context definition though. 
(You may have multiple configuration files for the same context, either by using imports or by having multiple values for contextConfigLocation in your web.xml)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean to say <context:property-placeholder location="..."/> should be present in the same file where the variables(like ${adapter.security.smpl.credentials}) are referenced? I do not find any such line.